# encoding must be a valid encoding error in process encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a simple program for process.stdin and process.stdout. But when i run the program and enter the value for stdout, it shows Error "TypeError: "encoding" must be a valid string encoding".
Here is my code .

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    process.stdout.write("Data >>>>", chunk);
});
process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    process.stderr.write("End!!!");
});
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line passes 2 arguments to `write`:

```
process.stdout.write("Data >>>>", chunk);
```

The second argument will be treated as an encoding, not as extra data to write.

Comment: Yeah...I would also add to fix use process.stdout.write("Data >>>>" + chunk);